# Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]/(7)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]/(7)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, ideals

Is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]/(7)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]/(7)$?

Here $(7)$ is the ideal generated by $7$.

If so, please tell me the explicit isomorphism. And how you  come up with the construction?

Comment: I added an answer in the linked dupe which gives some conceptual insight on problems like these.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks a lot!